# Gdx.files cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Typical `... cannot be resolved to a type` error. In this case however, project was set up by libgdx creator, so all references should have been properly created. Gdx.jar is in the Java Build path of the project. Javadoc says it is in `com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx` , which I have included (eclipse had no problem with that, but if I tried to include `com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.files it revolted). What could have happened?

Java-docs link- http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.html

Comment: Which project (common, desktop, android, etc) is the error in?  Did you spell "files" correctly? :)  Do any other imports work (try `Gdx.app.log(..)` or `Gdx.input.getX()`).  If none of that helps, please include a snippet of the offending code ...

Comment: Okay, found solution, it appears to have been eclipse problem. It doesn't work if I simply type the path, but if I select eclipse suggestions after each packet name, it works fine.